# How to compare string in javascript so that empty equals null

Tags: javascript, string, comparison

what can be the fastest code to have this check **:**

two strings are different only if they have different characters ?

so that

null == undefined == ''

now i use

```
if(!s1 && !!s2 
||
!!s1 && !s2
||
!!s1 && !!s2 && s1 != s2
)
```

but does not cover all cases

Comment: `(!s1 && !s2) || s1 === s2`…?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(s1 || '') == (s2 || '')
```

`||` will convert any falsey value to an empty string.

This will work as long as the variables are guaranteed to hold either a string, `null`, or `undefined`. If it can have a number, `0` will also be converted to an empty string, so `0 == ''` would be true.

Numeric strings are strings, so this will still work for them.

Comment: sadly yes, can have number

Comment: Why does the question say compare strings?

Comment: i have string to get user textbox, so user can write 0, but i manage it as string, so the title

Comment: That's not a number, it's a string. `||` doesn't treat `"0"` as falsey.